# Wait for a promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem with my code here is that the dom element that I am trying to get does not always exist when the code first runs, and if it does not exist then the promise will never be made.

Is it possible for me to wait for the promise to be made before I try to get it?

I want my last line of code to wait and only run when I make the promise, is this possible?

```
function identify_home(){           
    const ytd_home_page = $("ytd-browse.style-scope.ytd-page-manager")
    if (ytd_home_page.length){
        for (var i=0; i<ytd_home_page[0].children.length; i++){             
            if (ytd_home_page[i].attributes[0].value === "home"){
                return new Promise(res=>{
                    res(ytd_home_page[i])
                })

            }               
        }
    }                                   
}      

identify_home().then(res=>{
    console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: What does your markup look like? They way you're trying to interact with the DOM looks weird.

Comment: Actually I don't understand why you are using a Promise in this case anyway. There's nothing async going on here.

Comment: I suspect you misunderstand what a Promise does. I think you think a Promise will wait until something happens. That's not what it does.

Comment: Not sure if you're asking if you want to ensure the dom elem already exists before tidentify_home() is called?

Comment: You have to poll for the DOM element in a setInterval. When you find the element, clear the interval.

Comment: That is what I am originally doing, but I'm always trying to find ways to avoid set Intervals to optimize for CPU usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the Promise as a result from the function. Right now you are conditionally returning `undefined` or `Promise`.

Edit: I'm not sure yet what OP is actually trying to do. Using a Promise in a DOM query doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Code? or a example? How do I return it as a result

Comment: I really don't have to do it with promises, just wondered if it is a way to do it. Just doing it to not rewrite more code